# Read+Write intense queries - should I split into a read-write and a readonly db - and then replicate data?

Tags: azure-sql-database, application-design

### Background and problem - Providers read/write and block, end-users read

I run a system (up-to-date availability of resources), that constantly takes in a fair amount of data points from many different providers (think sources of data like scraped sites, API consumed etc), resulting in a lot of read/insert/deletes. At any given time, ~2-3 providers are read/writing in the table. There are about 2 million rows in the table.

#### Providers are OK

The providers reading/writing works just fine - does not matter if that process is sometimes a bit slow. No performance issues of any concern here.

#### Users not so much, sadness ensues

At the same time, users are querying the same database/table, and sometimes this seems to mean that blocking results in very long query-times. A normal query-time is 100ms, but every so often, 20-30 sec queries happen - which is not great.

### Potential solution

Other than throwing more virtual metal at the problem, I have considered a different design:

#### Two databases, replicated

- One database for all the providers to mess with, read, write
- Another database in which this table is read-only, so (hopefully) nothing will block user queries
- Replication from one to the other every 5-10 minutes (which I hope is intelligent enough to not cause blocking)

How does that sound? Would I be back at square one, because the replication causes the same issues?

Comment: Have you considered finding and eliminating the causes of "blocking" (if that's indeed what that is)? Might be easier than changing your architecture...

Comment: Are you really using Azure SQL Database and not one of the other Azure products?...as the default isolation level with Azure SQL Database is RCSI which means your readers shouldn't block your writers and your writers shouldn't block your readers. So I don't think you have a high concurrency / blocking issue. "*A normal query-time is 100ms, but every so often, 20-30 sec queries happen.*" - Even if you weren't using RCSI, this sounds less like blocking and more like an intermittent issue like parameter sniffing.

Comment: After reflection and digesting the top commen... Yes, at least I should understand the underlying issue before I pick a solution. My troubleshooting skills are oh so very rusty, but I will have to dust them off and see if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I upscaled the database server - and the problems just disappeared. Apparantly the queries were fine, nothing was blocking, but the amount of queries/data seems like it was too much for the size of instance, I was using.